# What columns do I select if I only want a count

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to count the results in my table... but I am usually confronted with a decision, what column do I select? Should I select the primary key? Wild Card? What has the most performance? Does it matter? Below is an example of how I call it

```
// Wild Card, I feel like this is the worst one for performance?

$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE status = ?";

// Only selecting one column? Is there a better way 

$query = "SELECT id FROM table WHERE status = ?";

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param('i',$status);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();

$returned_amount = $stmt->num_rows;

$stmt->free_result();
$stmt->close();
```

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(1) FROM table WHERE status = ?"`

Comment: @MarkBaker, is `count(1)` more efficient than `count(id)` or `count(*)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you want MySQL to handle the count, you can just do the following

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM `table` WHERE `field` = ?";
```

The `as count` part means that you can access the count as if it were a column.

Comment: why you want to count all the columns if you have any primary key.The performance will be better like that

Comment: The performance gain is negligible in this instance, and doing something COUNT(`id`) will only work if `id` is setup properly, and seeing as the op didn't specify, I assumed this would be best.

Answer (score 0):

You should `` SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `table` WHERE `status`=? ``, much more efficient ;)

Comment: This will only return the correct count if `id` is defined as `not null`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I would have thought that's a fairly safe assumption.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to count all the results of your query (ie: for pagination), you can use FOUND_ROWS() option:

In your main query you need to add SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS option just after SELECT and in second query you need to use FOUND_ROWS() function to get total number of rows.

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS id FROM table WHERE status = 'something' LIMIT 10;

SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
```

More info in [dev.mysql.com](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows)